# Exe produced with VS 2010 and VS 2005 loaded with a different offset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, executable, portable-executable

### Loading process image file different between VS 2005 and VS 2010

We have a post build step which modifies (patches) some locations in the executable. The patching process loads the process in the memory using `CreateProcess` and reads its code segment memory using `ReadProcessMemory`. Then a sequence `0x8D, 0x05, XX, XX, XX, XX, MAGIC` is searched in the memory, and the file is modified on the corresponding offset to contain a different code. The offset into the file is computed as the address of the instruction in the process memory space minus preferred load address of the exe. The exe is marked as /BASE:"0x400000" /DYNAMICBASE:NO /FIXED (no address randomization, no relocation).

The works fine with executables produced with VS 2005, however it fails when the exe is built using VS 2010. The sequence in the memory is found, but the content of the file at corresponding offset does not match. When searching the binary file, the corresponding code can be found 0xc00 earlier in the file.

When comparing the command lines, I can see there is [/OPT:WIN98](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) used for VS 2005 which is missing for VS 2010 and seems [not to be supported by the linker any more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

### Loading executable built by VS 2010

Now my question is:

- Where does this 0xc00 offset come from?
- Or, if my notion the process is loaded by reading the content of the exe file into memory defined by the load address is wrong or oversimplified, is there some documentation detailing how is process loaded in the memory (if possible including with handling of flags like like /OPT:WIN98 or /SWAPRUN)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems exe produced with /OPT:WIN98 has a slightly larger header (aligned to 4 KB). When this flag is not specified, the code is still loaded from 0x401000, but the header is only 0x400 instead of 0x1000, resulting in the image offset of 0xc00.

Comment: Seems reasonable, as Windows 98 preferred the files to be page aligned for slightly faster load time. Not supported anymore, so it seems equally reasonable to remove the option.